# Node fs.unlink: error object is different on different machines

Tags: node.js, fs, unlink

I apologize if I missed a similar question - I scoured the site and could not find anything.

My code looks like this (after having promisified fs.unlink):

```
return unlinkAsync(file)
    .catch((err) => {
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
            // Not a concern - file didn't exist, and that's ok
        } else {
            // Unexpected - propagate it up
            throw err;
        }
    });
```

**The problem**: on my machine (OSX Sierra, node 5.9.1) err.code exists, and things are handled correctly when there's no file to delete. **However**, on another machine -- same OS and version of Node -- err.code *does not exist* -- we see a property called 'cause', which has a 'code' property, but no err.code.

I searched through the node source code (only been coding node for a month, but I don't think I missed anything), and could not find anything but expectations around e.code.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
John

Comment: Have you ruled out any third party modules/addons?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't even think of that (too new to node) - however, I'll check that with the dev whose machine doesn't expose err.code - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it came down to an older version of Bluebird (1.2.4) on the other dev machine (thanks @mscdex!) -- the latest version (3.4.7) provides err.code, and the older did not.

However, at a deeper level this happened because I neglected to update our package.json to include the version of Bluebird I expected -- lesson learned.

Thanks!